# Doing math on UInt64 is unwrapping it

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, jsctypes

I have a `var blah = ctypes.UInt64('65')`, the 65 is really anything. I need to do math on that, but when I do:

`console.log(blah * ctypes.UInt64('2')` it removes the `ctypes.UInt64` wrap. I need to keep that wrap so I can pass it into something else, I know I can re-wrap it, but whats the proper way to do math on `UInt64` and `Int64` please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API/library to do math on js-ctypes Int64 types.

You'll need to unwrap and re-wrap as needed and of course do enough error checking and handling to know when it is [safe to unwrap stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24353278/484441) and what math operations might lose precision (>53bit) and/or overflow numbers.

If you cannot use regular JS double precision float math, because you really need those 64-bit, then you'll need read up on bignum math and how to do it with small-numbers, or find a suitable bignum library. However, the numbers from your example do not require this.

And avoid doing int64 math in the first place, if possible; but of course, that is not always possible.

Comment: Aw drats ok re-wrapping it is. Yep I'll definitely use that post you gave me earlier to check bits before i do the math.