# Adding two 64 bit number using free pascal

Tags: assembly

I just started learning assembly and can't quite understand how to add two 64 bit numbers. I'm using Free Pascal IDE, could you please give me working example with comments?
I looked through relevant questions here, but it's still not clear for me

Comment: In 32 or 64-bit mode? in 64-bit mode obviously a single add instruction is enough. In 32-bit mode long additions there are also tons of questions on this site already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652654/adding-64-bit-numbers-using-32-bit-arithmetic

Answer (score 0):

First of all x86 architecture doesn't (usually) allow operations on two memory operands. So at least one operand must be in the register.

Next, there are only a few ternary operations, so usually you work with two operands. That is you can't do (if to express in C notation) `a = b + c` but only `a += b`.

Next, you should specify which mode 32-bit or 64-bit you use. For 64-bit mode the addition is as simple as: `add rax, rdx` (rax += rdx). For 32-bit mode you need two operations: `add eax, edx` and then `adc ecx, ebx` (ecx:eax += ebx:edx) Here `adc` is 'addition with carry' - must be after carry flag is set by the first addition (but before it's changed by any other operation).